# Editing Software Platform Inferred Flags with TCL command in Xilinx SDK

Tags: eclipse, sdk, tcl, xilinx

I am trying to create an SDK project totally with tcl commands. I have only one problem left which is adding -lm option to Software Platform Inferred Flags. How can I add the -lm option to Software Platform Inferred Flags with tcl command?

[image: Software Platform Inferred Flags]

Comment: That looks like Eclipse, which means I'd imagine you do it by modifying an XML file somewhere in the project configuration. I have no idea which file, of course.

Comment: Thank you @DonalFellows, I just modified the .cproject file and it worked. How can I accept this as an answer?

Comment: If Donal does not make an actual answer post, you can't. To help future readers of this question, I'd recommend you add an answer yourself, detailing the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I opened the .cproject file in the project directory, find the **Software Platform Inferred Flag option** under the related toolchain linker(I am using ARM v7 gcc), add the -lm option to the value and then saved the file.

```
<tool id="xilinx.gnu.armv7.c.toolchain.linker.debug.1438648523" name="ARM v7 gcc linker" superClass="xilinx.gnu.armv7.c.toolchain.linker.debug">
    <option id="xilinx.gnu.linker.inferred.swplatform.lpath.1492945636" name="Software Platform Library Path" superClass="xilinx.gnu.linker.inferred.swplatform.lpath" valueType="libPaths">
        <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="../../sw_bsp/ps7_cortexa9_0/lib"/>
    </option>
    <option id="xilinx.gnu.linker.inferred.swplatform.flags.715040693" name="Software Platform Inferred Flags" superClass="xilinx.gnu.linker.inferred.swplatform.flags" valueType="libs">
        <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="-Wl,--start-group,-lxilffs,-lxil,-lgcc,-lc,-lm,--end-group"/>
    </option>
    <option id="xilinx.gnu.c.linker.option.lscript.1697357619" name="Linker Script" superClass="xilinx.gnu.c.linker.option.lscript" value="../src/lscript.ld" valueType="string"/>
    <option id="xilinx.gnu.c.link.option.ldflags.126303999" name="Linker Flags" superClass="xilinx.gnu.c.link.option.ldflags" value=" -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfpu=vfpv3 -mfloat-abi=hard -Wl,-build-id=none -specs=Xilinx.spec" valueType="string"/>
    <inputType id="xilinx.gnu.linker.input.2096600882" superClass="xilinx.gnu.linker.input">
        <additionalInput kind="additionalinputdependency" paths="$(USER_OBJS)"/>
        <additionalInput kind="additionalinput" paths="$(LIBS)"/>
    </inputType>
    <inputType id="xilinx.gnu.linker.input.lscript.430006367" name="Linker Script" superClass="xilinx.gnu.linker.input.lscript"/>
</tool>
```